# Does The set of two ordered pairs need to be itself ordered for it to be equal to a set of two ordered pairs?

Tags: group-theory, discrete-mathematics

$$< <2,7>, <5,7> > ~= ~<<5,7> , <2,7> >~~?$$ 
Does The set of ordered pairs need to be itself ordered for equivalent term? (For the first notation be equal to the second the pairs $~2,~7~$ need to be in the first ordered pair by the order.of the pairs and the second $~5,~7~?$

Comment: What? Your question doesn't seem to make much sense. Try to write clearly what your doubt is.

Comment: That really didn't make things much better...and I'm beginning to suspect you didn't actually mean "group" but rather **"set"** ...didn't you?! Because "group" is a very precise algebraic structure...

Comment: Yes , im sorry.. this is my first formal course

Comment: In a set, the order how the elements are written down does not matter, although usually they are written down in increasing order. In the case of ordered pairs we would additionally have to decide how we order them (for example lexicographically)

Comment: Got it, thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In *any* set as such there is no order and no multiplicity. This means that the sets

$$\{1,2\},\;\{2,1\},\;\{1,1,2,1,2\},\;\{1,2,2,2,2,2,1,1,1,2,2,2,1,2,1,2\}$$

are **exactly one and the very same set** : the set with two different elements, named $\;1,\,2\;$ in it.

And it doesn't matter what kind of objects form the set! Thus, the sets $\;\{\,(2,7),\,(5,7)\,\}\;,\;\;\{\,(5,7)_,\,(2,7)\,\}\;$ are exactly the same as they have exactly the same elements .

What is true though, is that in a *cartesian product* (i.e., a set whose elements are **ordered** pairs), for each element the order is very important, meaning: the *element* $\;(2,7)\;$ in some (cartesian product) set  is **not the same** as the element $\;(7,2)\;$ ...unless for some reason we're given that $\;2=7\;$ ...!

Comment: Great!, Thank you